# programmatically create .touchUpInside event for UITextField

Tags: swift, uipickerview

Added a pickerView using a UITextField.

I am trying to trigger the pickerView programmatically.

```
    func myTypeDetector (textfield: UITextField) {
    typeLabel.delegate = self
    self.setType(textField: typeLabel)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    typeLabel.addTarget(self, action: #selector(NewSpeciesVC.myTypeDetector(textfield:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
}
```

I have found how to do this via UIButton

```
self.typeLabel.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
```

However, this is not working for the UITextField.

I would like to programmatically create the event with the TextField, or create the PickerView event using a UIButton.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the picker view set as the text field's `inputView`? If not, how is the picker tied to the text field?

Comment: you want to call a method when you click on the textfield, right?

Comment: @3stud1ant3, no.  I want to trigger the textField at the end of a separate func.

Comment: Basically, a pickerView that can initiate without any actions from the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to do the same thing and figured it out:

```
self.typelabel.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Comment: Thank you for following up on this.  While I changed the solution, this answer will help me in the future.